# Bash Script to create a DMG

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I am trying to automate (using bash script)creation of JHFS+ formatted,DMG file on a macOS.
The script should be able to intake user supplied:

- size of the DMG in GB's
- destination of the DMG
- type of filesystem (HFS+,JHFS+,APFS,FAT32,ExFAT or UDF)
- volume name
- the name of the DMG to be created.

I used the following:

```
date
read -p "Enter the size of the DMG:   " size        
read -e -p "Enter the destination of the DMG:   " dest  
read -p "Enter the filesystem (HFS+,JHFS+,APFS,FAT32,ExFAT or UDF)  :" fs
read -p "Enter the Volume name :" volname
read -p "Enter the name of the DMG:" name

hdiutil create -fs {"$fs"} -size "$size" -volname "{$volname}" "{$dest\/$name}"
exit
```

Issue is when the script is executed,with size mentioned as "1g" (1GB),I get the following error:

```
hdiutil: create failed - Invalid argument
```

Suggestions to improve the script are welcome.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets `{` and `}` around the variables are wrong and the escaped slash `\/` doesn't work.

I changed `$dest` and `$name` to a combined `$dest` and added default values. For the size I added a little hint for the most common sizes.

```
#!/bin/bash

defaults=( 1g HFS+ "my volume" ~/Desktop/myvolume.dmg )

read -ep "Enter the size (??m|??g|??t) [${defaults[0]}] " size 
read -ep "Enter the filesystem (HFS+, JHFS+, APFS, FAT32, ExFAT, UDF) [${defaults[1]}] " fs
read -ep "Enter the volume name [${defaults[2]}] " volname
read -ep "Enter the image destination [${defaults[3]}] " dest

hdiutil create -size "${size:-${defaults[0]}}" -fs "${fs:-${defaults[1]}}" -volname "${volname:-${defaults[2]}}" "${dest:-${defaults[3]}}"
```